# Show that A contains two numbers $s$ and $t$ such that $s-t=9$.

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $A \subset K$ where $K=\{1,...,100\}$ with #$A=55$. Show that A contains two numbers $s$
>   and $t$ such that $s-t=9$.
>
> Hint: Use Rule of Double Counting

From my notes, the rule of Double Counting is:

Let $(X,Y,I)$ be the incidence system and for $a\in X$ let $r(a)$ denote the number of elements of $T$ incident to $a$, and let $r(b)$ for $b\in Y$ is the number of elements incident to $b$. Then the following relation holds:

$$\sum_{a\in X} r(a)= \sum_{b\in Y} r(b) $$

$\mathbf{Attempt}$

I think that we take $X=K$ and $Y=A$ and the incident is that $s-t=9$ ,so hence that would mean $$\sum_{a\in S} r(a)=55$$

However, I'm confused at what to do with the right hand side of the rule, how do we choose the elements of this set where $s-t=9$ is satisfied?

Any Hints would be a great help, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**  Let $B = \{x + 9 \mid x \in A\}$.  Then $|B| = 55$.  Moreover, $B \subset \{10, \ldots, 109\}$.  Therefore, $A \cup B \subset \{1, \ldots, 109\}$.  Since there are $55$ elements in $A$ and $55$ elements in $B$, they cannot all be distinct.

Comment: Thank you, that was a great help - worked it through and I think I got it.